# Why is MongoDB shell version differen than db.version()?

Tags: mongodb

I just updated from MongoDB 2.4.9 to 2.4.10 using `brew upgrade mongodb`.

Why is the reported shell version different than what is reported by db.version()?

```
>>> mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.10
connecting to: test
Server has startup warnings: 
Sat Apr  5 13:13:03.414 [initandlisten] 
Sat Apr  5 13:13:03.414 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
>>> db.version()
2.4.9
```

> 

Comment: I think that you just have not updated everything properly. In my case  the version is the same.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the confirmation that they are the same on your system. There is probably something simple I'm missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a different version of the MongoDB shell compared with the MongoDB server. The second line of your output is reporting the shell version, whereas the db.version function reports the server version.

Have you restarted your MongoDB server process after running the brew update? This would only have changed the binaries on disk and not have altered any running instances.

You should also check the path of the MongoD binary and the Mongo shell binary to see if they come from the same path.

Comment: You nailed it. It was because I had my MongoDB server running. Once I restarted both reported 2.4.10.